# How to check to see if there's an array within an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**The Problem**

I want to test for the presence of an array inside of an array. For example, if my array is this:

```
let arr = ["all", ['>', 'PSF', 10]]
```

I want something like this to work:

```
let segment = ['>', 'PSF', 10]
arr.indexOf(segment) // would be equal to 1, in this case
```

**What actually happens**

arr.indexOf(segment) is currently -1, since I believe in JavaScript `[] != []` due to the way it checks the array memory location.

At any rate, what would be the recommended way of testing to see if a specific array currently exists within an array? I also tried .includes(), but it seems to work the same way that indexOf works (so it failed).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript for how to compare two arrays for equal elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to create a function that compare 2 arrays, (the implementation will depend on your needs) , for example :

```
const compareArrays = (a1, a2) => Array.isArray(a1) && Array.isArray(a2) && a1.length === a2.length && a1.every((v, i) => v === a2[i])
```

You will need to define this function, because your array `segment`, may be more complicated, (i.e contains other arrays)

Then use `some` to check whether your original array contains the array (`segment`) :

```
arr.some(element => compareArrays(segment, element) )
```

Or `findIndex`, to get the index of the matching array (or -1 if no matching array exists)

```
arr.findIndex(element => compareArrays(segment, element) )
```

Comment: careful, this will throw if any `element` *(or `segment`)* is `null` or `undefined`

Comment: How would I get the index value out of this though? I'd like to be able to see where the matching array is in the array i'm searching

Comment: In this case use, `findIndex` instead of `some`

Comment: @LGSon, I already mentionned this in my answer. (the `compareArrays`  need to be updated depending on the arrays content)